# How to conduct meta analysis for studies that have used repeated cross section surveys to report prevalence

Tags: meta-analysis, effect-size, meta-regression, metafor, meta-learning

When conducting meta-analysis on prevalence of disease, few studies have reported prevalences using different rounds of cross-sectional surveys. When analyzing such studies shall I take each reported survey for each time period as different observation or there are any guidelines for such publications.
For example, a study published prevalence at three different time periods using 3 different cross-sectional surveys, I am considering each time period as different study and including them in meta-analysis as different observations.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A key assumption of meta-analysis is that the effect sizes are independent which they clearly are not here. Options include: (1) averaging within studies, possibly using a fixed effects analysis, (2) using a multi-level meta-analysis.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Here I am trying to estimate pooled prevalence. Still do I need to go for averaging within studies or mutli-level analysis ??

Comment: I do not see that as making a difference to what you should do.

Comment: Sir I have searched for paper on using repeated cross sectional surveys as a data points for meta analysis as different points. I did not find any, if you any papers, can you please do share with me. Or the material on how to write it for method sections. Thanks in advance.